# Where are the NetworkManager logs?

Tags: network-manager, log

A previous poster on the regular forums ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843991 ) said `/var/log/daemon.log`, but I don't seem to have such a file. Do I need to enable logging?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can find the Network Manager logs in `/var/log/syslog`, which acts as a catch-all for log messages (unless you have changed [rsyslog](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rsyslogd)'s default configuration).

Comment: Try setting log to "info" first: `sudo dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.SetLogging string:"info" string:""` (from http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/Debugging)

Answer (score 41):

The answers are now obsolete (2017), the logs are now here

`journalctl -u NetworkManager`

**NOTE**: this will display all NetworkManager's log since it has been installed. If you want to limit the amount of logs to the time the system has been booted instead, use the `-b` option: `journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

See the man page of [journalctl(1)](https://manpages.org/journalctl) for further options and filters.

Comment: `journalctl -f -u NetworkManager` is better to following logs

Comment: If you see --No Entries---   
You may install it first!

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate Where are NetworkManager log files located for the network-manager package:

From the man pages:

`man NetworkManager`

> ```
>   --log-domains=<domain1>,<domain2>, ...
>          Sets which operations are logged to the log destination (usually syslog).   By  default,
>          most  domains  are  logging-enabled.  See NetworkManager.conf(5) for more information on
>          log levels and domains.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 or later,

```
journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
```

should show all the NetworkManager logs.